# User Email is not fetched from backend

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, spring-security

The problem faced is when we connect sts with the react for adding expenses, the data of user email is not getting fetched from the user table

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>{

    Boolean existsByEmail(String email);

    Optional<User> findByEmail(String email);
}

@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        User existingUser = userRepository.findByEmail(email).orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found for the email:"+email));
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(existingUser.getEmail(), existingUser.getPassword(), getGrantedAuthority(existingUser));
    }
    private Collection<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthority(User user) {
        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));
        
        return authorities;
    }
}

public interface ExpenseService {

    

    Expense saveExpenseDetails(Expense expense);
}

@Service
public class ExpenseServiceImpl implements ExpenseService {

    @Autowired
    private ExpenseRepository expenseRepo;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
@Override
    public Expense saveExpenseDetails(Expense expense) {
        expense.setUser(userService.getLoggedInUser());
        return expenseRepo.save(expense);
    }
}



@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder bcryptEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

@Override
    public User getLoggedInUser() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        String email = authentication.getName();
        return userRepository.findByEmail(email).orElseThrow(() ->new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found for the email "+email));
    }
}



@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @PostMapping("/expenses")ublic Expense saveExpenseDetails(@Valid @RequestBody Expense expense) {
        return expenseService.saveExpenseDetails(expense);
    }
```

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Base from "./Base";
import axios from "axios";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";

class AddExpenseComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      name: "",
      amount: "",
      category: "",
      date: "",
    };

    this.changeNameHandler = this.changeNameHandler.bind(this);
    this.changePriceHandler = this.changePriceHandler.bind(this);
    this.changecategoryHandler = this.changecategoryHandler.bind(this);
    this.changeDateHandler = this.changeDateHandler.bind(this);
    this.saveOrUpdateExpense = this.saveOrUpdateExpense.bind(this);
  }

  saveOrUpdateExpense = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let expense = {
      name: this.state.name,
      amount: this.state.amount,
      category: this.state.category,
      date: this.state.date,
    };
    console.log("expense => " + JSON.stringify(expense));
    axios.post("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/expenses", expense,{ headers: { "Authorization": localStorage.getItem("jwtToken")}});
    toast.success("Expense added successfully")
  };

 
  changeNameHandler = (event) => {
    this.setState({ name: event.target.value });
  };

  changePriceHandler = (event) => {
    this.setState({ amount: event.target.value });
  };

  changecategoryHandler = (event) => {
    this.setState({ category: event.target.value });
  };

  changeDateHandler = (event) => {
    this.setState({ date: event.target.value });
  };

  cancel() {
    this.props.history.push("/user/dashboard");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Base>
      <div>
        <br></br>
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="card col-md-6 offset-md-3 offset-md-3">
              <h3 className="text-center">Add Expense</h3>
              <div className="card-body">
                <form>
                  <div className="form-group">
                    <label> Name: </label>
                    <input
                      placeholder="Name"
                      name="name"
                      className="form-control"
                      required
                      value={this.state.name}
                      onChange={this.changeNameHandler}
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="form-group">
                    <label> Price: </label>
                    <input
                      placeholder="Price"
                      name="amount"
                      className="form-control"
                      required
                      value={this.state.amount}
                      onChange={this.changePriceHandler}
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="form-group">
                    <label for="category"> category: </label>
                    <select
                      class="form-control"
                      id="category"
                      value={this.state.category}
                      required
                      onChange={this.changecategoryHandler}
                    >
                      <option value="Food">Food</option>
                      <option value="Toys">Toys</option>
                      <option value="Stationary">Stationary</option>
                      <option value="Electronics">Electronics</option>
                      <option value="Education">Education</option>
                      <option value="Insurance">Insurance</option>
                      <option value="Clothing">Clothing</option>
                      <option value="Transportation">Transportation</option>
                      <option value="Medicine">Medicine</option>
                      <option value="Groceries">Groceries</option>
                      <option value="House Utilities">House Utilities</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div className="form-group">
                    <label> Date: </label>{" "}
                    <input
                      placeholder="Date"
                      type="date"
                      name="date"
                      className="form-control"
                      required
                      value={this.state.date}
                      onChange={this.changeDateHandler}
                    />{" "}
                  </div>
                  <br></br>
                  <button
                    className="btn btn-success"
                    onClick={this.saveOrUpdateExpense}
                  >
                    Save
                  </button>
                  <button
                    className="btn btn-danger"
                    onClick={this.cancel.bind(this)}
                    style={{ marginLeft: "10px" }}
                  >
                    Cancel
                  </button>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </Base>
    );
  }
}

export default AddExpenseComponent;
```

The backend code is working with the postman but its not working when connected with the react

Error in the console

org.hibernate.SQL: select user0_.id as id1_1_, user0_.address as address2_1_, user0_.email as email3_1_, user0_.name as name4_1_, user0_.password as password5_1_, user0_.phoneno as phoneno6_1_ from users_tables user0_ where user0_.email=?

o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder  : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [anonymousUser]

.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver: Resolved[org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException: User not found for the email anonymousUser]

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is but the "Error" that you see is not an error at all. 
 It's just telling you that it can't find a record in the database that matches your query.

Comment: I want to fetch the user email from the database of users when I am adding the expense. But from the console, it is binding to the correct user id but cannot fetch the email from it. The user table already has the values present in it.